# I can't add any rule to iptables / iptables not saving

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding

I want to forward tcp and udp traffic from wireguard ip address (10.66.66.2) to 0.0.0.0, but iptables doesn't want to cooperate.

OS is Oracle Linux 8, I use yum as package manager. Firewall.d is disabled.

`iptables -S` gives completely different output than `cat /etc/iptables/rules`

I want to apply few rules like this `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.66.66.2 --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination 0.0.0.0:27015` but it doesn't seem to register any changes in iptables - traffic is not routed to 0.0.0.0.

I reinstalled iptables and iptables-service, added rules directly to /etc/iptables/rules. that didn't help

My temporary solution is `socat TCP-LISTEN:27015,fork,reuseaddr TCP:0.0.0.0:27015` - it works but it's not as convenient as iptables.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `0.0.0.0` instead of the regular `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Yes, when I host something on 127.0.0.1 it doesn't work under public ip address. But it doesn't matter for my problem with iptables - rule with 127.0.0.1 also won't be saved

Comment: I mean as part of the NAT rule. Sure you would normally configure the service to _listen on_ 0.0.0.0, but that does not mean your clients would _connect to_ 0.0.0.0 – it only means "all addresses" in the context of establishing listeners, not in the context of routing actual packets (where you'd use one of the host's actual addresses instead).

Comment: ok, I think i get it now. So I want to listen on 10.0.0.114

Comment: No, your app can listen on 0.0.0.0 as before, but the firewall rule would need to specify 10.0.0.114 (is this a different machine? if it's a different machine, how did you expect "0.0.0.0" to lead to it?)

Comment: 10.0.0.114 is the same machine.
But I still have problem with saving iptables. I can add any rules and they do not exist

Comment: Are you looking for them in the `-t nat` table?

Comment: Yes. I reinstalled iptables and iptables-service once again and now it is saving the changes. I successfully opened the port  27015, checked it by nc -l 27015. But I still can't forward traffic from wireguard client 10.66.66.2 to 10.0.0.114